# Temp table empty after sql insert exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec

Very confused as to why the final `select * from #tempTbl` is empty.

When I run this, everything else works fine, but I need the results in a temp table to continue with the next step of the stored procedure. I've been searching every forum possible including this one, and cannot fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTbl
(
     POID VARCHAR(15), 
     UPC VARCHAR(15), 
     QtyOrdered int, 
     DateOrdered date, 
     Closed bit
)

insert into #tempTbl (POID, UPC, QtyOrdered, DateOrdered, Closed)
    exec dbo.sp_executesql @as4sql;

--exec (@as4sql)

select * from #tempTbl
```

Update:

Here's my set:

```
set @as4sql = 'INSERT INTO tblPODetail 
    (POID, UPC, QtyOrdered, DateOrdered, Closed) 
    (SELECT pod.PONumber, pod.UPC, pod.QtyOrdered, 1, 0 
    FROM [awx].[dbo].[POLines] pol 
    JOIN [awx].[dbo].[PODetails] pod 
        ON pol.PONumber = pod.PONumber 
    LEFT JOIN tblPODetail p  
        ON p.POID = pod.PONumber  
    WHERE p.POID IS NULL...
```

Comment: have you verified that `@as4sql` is returning rows when run outside of the `insert` statement?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reproducible. [see here for online demo](http://rextester.com/JZH78585)

Comment: Yes, the primary purpose of the as4sql is to insert into permanent table, and it does so every time.  The record set isn't cleared after this is it?  I'm not clearing in code.  My intention is it to have @as4sql fill the permanent table, then fill the temp table where I really only need all the records from one of the fields (UPC).

Comment: Here's my set:
set @as4sql =
'INSERT INTO tblPODetail (POID, UPC, QtyOrdered, DateOrdered, Closed)
(SELECT pod.PONumber, pod.UPC, pod.QtyOrdered, 1, 0
FROM [awx].[dbo].[POLines] pol 
JOIN [awx].[dbo].[PODetails] pod on pol.PONumber = pod.PONumber 
Left JOIN tblPODetail p ON p.POID = pod.PONumber
WHERE p.POID IS NULL......

Comment: @Jim SO removed your setting of the variable. Can you post in your original question?

Comment: @scsimon:  what removed the setting of the variable?  "SO"??  Sorry, not sure what you're saying here.  I do believe there's something that's clearing it though.  I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: SO = StackOverflow (short hand). Your variable is just inserting rows tblPODetail. It doesn't *return* anything. Thus, nothing will be inserted into your temp.

Comment: OH!!! Okay!!! That makes total sense.  How unfortunate that I can't use the data set twice.  I guess I'll just run the query again to get the field I need.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all

Comment: I would drop the dynamic sql portion of this as it doesn't provide any benefit. You could use the OUTPUT clause to stick the data into your temp table.